# Require dependency to get Rails subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following setup:

app/models/my_module/service.rb

```
module MyModule
  class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.types
      self.subclasses
    end

    def self.raw_types
      self.types.map { |c| c.name.split("::").last }
    end
  end
end

require_dependency "my_module/service/rack"
require_dependency "my_module/service/rails"
require_dependency "my_module/service/sinatra"
```

app/models/my_module/service/rack.rb:

```
module MyModule
  class Service::Rack < Service
  end
end
```

app/models/my_module/service/rails.rb:

```
module MyModule
  class Service::Rails < Service
  end
end
```

app/models/my_module/service/sinatra.rb:

```
module MyModule
  class Service::Sinatra < Service
  end
end
```

That works so far, but now my question:

Why I have to add these three lines:

```
require_dependency "my_module/service/rack"
require_dependency "my_module/service/rails"
require_dependency "my_module/service/sinatra"
```

to my service.rb file?

If I don't add the three lines:

```
MyModule::Service.raw_types
=> []
```

If I add the three lines:

```
MyModule::Service.raw_types
=> ["Rack", "Rails", "Sinatra"]
```

Anybody an idea?

Btw: I use Ruby 2.0.0-preview1, Rails 4.0.0.rc1 and create a new Rails engine with

```
rails plugin new MyModule
```

Comment: Does MyModule::Service.types work?

Comment: Is the question why do have to require the files or why the array gets populated? When you require the files you add 3 classes which all subclass Service, hence `Service.subclasses` returns those 3 classes.

Comment: Idea: one of the files monkey-patches `subclasses` into Class.

Comment: BettySt: only if I require the files in my parent class. Kris: my question is why I have to require the three files, and not the method call, which points to the subclasses requires my files automatically, because the classes are called through the parent class implicit. User: what do you mean? I have not defined any monkey patch yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, in the development environment, Rails will autoload constants in the usual subdirectories of `app`, by looking in the conventional place (e.g., `/app/models/my_module/service/rack.rb` for `MyModule::Service::Rack`). This autoloading happens when the constant is referenced for the first time, not on app initialization.

But this means that before the constant is referenced, the file that defines it is not loaded unless it is explicitly required.

Thus, when you call `MyModule::Service.raw_types`, `MyModule::Service` is loaded from `app/models/my_module/service.rb` if it isn't already defined. However, if no reference has yet been made to its subclasses, those constants won't be defined *unless* the files that define them are explicitly required. Thus, requiring those files in the file that *is* autoloaded on that method call makes them available.

Moral: if you want to ensure that the subclasses of `MyModule::Service` are always defined whenever `MyModule::Service` is, you need to require them in `/app/models/my_module/service.rb`

Comment: Okay I thought that already, but I hoped, that Rails fixes the autoloading while the method get called, because the classes are needed through a parent class method call.. could it be a Rails bug? I understand the loading from a "ruby view", but not from the "rails view"..

Comment: This is not a bug in Rails. How is the application supposed to know that those constants are needed when it doesn't even know they exist? I don't think there's any harm in requiring your subclasses in the file that defines the superclass. Alternatively, you could load them all in config/boot.rb so they'll be there on app initialization.

Comment: But it would be really good, if Rails has such a behavior that it searches the sub folder which is called like the module around the parent class to check if there are subclasses defined. That would be great :). But anyway I just will load them all through the rails initialization process.

Comment: Btw +1 for your explanation.

Comment: so according to this explanation, if you leave out the `require_dependency` and then called one of the subclass e.g. `MyModule::Service::Sinatra.new`, if the next call was `MyModule::Service.raw_types` it would it return just `['Sinatra']` ?